# How to get only child elements outside a certain class jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image]

This is the scenario. The black element has an ID and theoretically I want to select like this:

```
$("#someid .class2")...
```

I don't want to get the element inside the red element though. And yes, the classes are written correctly, the red element and black have the same class...

Also, there may be elements between any of these elements (like in nested - the green element inside the red one might be nested inside multiple other elements, so the red one is not necessarily the parent)

So basically ignore all class1 elements other than itself.
How can I get this?

Edit: I added 2 examples. The query, whatever it is, should work for both.

Example 1

```
<div id="someid" class="class1">
  <div class="class1">
    <div>
      <span class="class2"></span> <---- NO
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="class2"></span>  <-----YES
  </div>
</div>
```

Example 2

```
<div id="someid" class="class1">
  <div>
    <div>
      <div class="class1">
        <div>
          <span class="class2"></span>  <---NO
        </div>
      </div>
      <span class="class2"></span>  <-------YES
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="class1">
    <span class="class2"></span>   <--------NO
  </div>
  <span class="class2"></span>  <-----------YES
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried with $("#someid > .class2") this css selector only gets direct childs

Comment: The problem is that the 2nd class2 element might not be direct child, as I said, there may be elements between any of them (or rather nested)

Comment: Please provide HTML of possible scenarios and the desired outcome of each scenario. Just 2 or 3 should be sufficient. A picture is great, but people with visual impairments and search engines won't be able to understand this question.

Comment: I edited with 2 examples

Comment: I just realized I can just mark elements inside class 1 `$("#someid .class1 .class2").addClass("ignore")` and then `$("#someid .class2:not('.ignore')")` and then remove the ignore class.. but maybe it can be done in a query

Answer (score 0):

```js
console.log(document.querySelectorAll("#test1 > .class2"))
```

```html
<div id="test1" class="class1">
  <div class="class1">
    <div class="class2">test 3</div>
  </div>

  <div class="class2">test 1</div>
</div>
```

In this example im using vanilla javascript but with jQuery the css selector it would be the same.

Comment: This only works for direct children right? The picture is misleading, maybe I shouldn't have put it, because there is a huge difference between being child and not being, and in my case it's possible that the green elements are inside many other elements

Comment: Yes works for direct children. Mmm understood you need a solution for nested elements.